# Read logs of other app

Tags: android, android-logcat

I have two android application, (not on play store), I install both app in a mobile, Now i want to read all logs of Application1 into Application2, how can i do it,
I'm able to read inapplog, not others, using this code:

```
Process logcat;
final StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
try {
logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d"});
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logcat.getInputStream()),4*1024);
String line;
String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        log.append(line);
        log.append(separator);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Need Help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127349/how-to-read-android-log-cat-progamatically-for-other-applications

Comment: In above post he is saying can't  read logcat above Android 4.1. Then how Android Studio is reading and showing our logs in logcat.